# How to extract each item in an array and add as column name

Tags: python

Updated:
I have a numpy array, and would like to use them to create labels. How should I do this?

Apologies, still learning how to write a proper for loop :)

```
  array = [ 1  8  9 10 24 25 34 40 51 72]
  labels=[]        
  labels.append('nar' +str(x) for x in array)
  # use labels as column name 
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=X, index=labels, columns=labels)
```

The above function returns an error.

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 10, placement implies 1
    enter code here
```

Comment: First of all, you should read the error message and change your code accordingly. E.g. if it is something like `l is not defined` then look at `l` and say "yeah, I meant `list`, not `l`"

Comment: Hint: you can't add a string and an integer.

Comment: 1) Don't shadow the built-in list function by naming a variable `list`, that's a recipe for trouble. 2) Please provide the full error traceback of any errors you're receiving so that we can understand the nature of your problem. 3) what is `l` in `range(l)`

Comment: Updated my question. Apologies, it should be a numpy array, not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so firstly, the list definition is incorrect. All items in a list need to be comma separated as follows:

`l= [ 1, 8, 9, 10, 24, 25, 34, 40, 51, 72]`

You can create the labels as follows:

```
 l= [ 1 , 8 , 9 ,10 ,24 ,25 ,34, 40, 51, 72]
 # Make labels
 labels = ['nar' + str(i) for i in l]
 print(labels)
```

*Note:* You need to type cast (i) to str, since it is an integer it cannot be directly appended to a str.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by looping through the list and adding the number to the "nar" to create a label.

Example :

```py
list = [1, 8, 9, 10, 24, 25, 34, 40, 51, 72]
labels = []
for i in range(len(list)):
    labels.append("nar" = str(list[i]))
```

Comment: Side note: in Python you almost never want to write `for i in range(len(something)):`. Instead, here you'd just write `for i in list`. If you really want that index variable too for some reason, use `for index, item in enumerate(my_list)`.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, got this error: `labels.append("nar" = str(list[i]))
                 ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`